# Has the option to disable .png compression been removed from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I can't find the option to disable .png compression in Xcode 5 (http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html)

has it been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your target's "Build Settings" tab, select "All" option (not "Basic") and then type "compress" in the search bar, and you'll see it immediately. It's under "Packaging".

[image: compress png files]